# What is the maximum size of smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I'm developing a smart contract and yesterday I couldn't deploy it into testnet with error:

```
root@698a02be20d9:/# cleos --verbose set contract myaccount /work/mycontract -p myaccount@active
Reading WASM from /work/mycontract/mycontract.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3200000: http exception
Error Details:
Unable to read http response: End of file
Stack Trace:
httpc.cpp:100 do_txrx
```

The size of mycontract.wasm is 513KB for now.
There is no problem with deployment of smaller contracts. What can I do with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

512 KB

EOSIO does not impose this limit on contract size, but it has a limit on max transaction size, which is 512KB.

Since the contract is set by a "setcode" action on eosio contract, de facto the limit is 512KB.